How do I implement pagination in Select2 using Livewire Volt?

I'm working on a project where I've implemented a dynamic dropdown feature using Laravel Livewire. The dropdown displays branches based on the selected bank. However, I'm encountering a performance issue with a specific bank that has over 1600 branches, leading to slow rendering of the dropdown options.
Problem Description
When selecting a bank from the dropdown, the Livewire component fetches all branches associated with that bank. This works fine for most banks, but for banks with a large number of branches (e.g., 1600+), the dropdown becomes slow to render due to loading all branches at once.
Code Implementation
Below is the Laravel Livewire Volt responsible for populating the dynamic dropdown:
<?php
use function Livewire\Volt\{rules, state, mount};
use Livewire\Volt\Component;
use App\Models\Branch;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
new class extends Component {
    public $selectedBranch, $bank_id;

    #[On('branchDynamicDropdown')]
    public function with(): array
    {
        $branch = Branch::select('id', 'bank_id', 'code', 'name', 'region');
        if ($this->bank_id == null) {
            $branch = $branch->get();
        } else {
            $branch = $branch->where('bank_id', $this->bank_id)->get();
        }
        return [
            'branch' => $branch,
        ];
    }

    #[On('branch-created')]
    public function setBranch($id): void
    {
        $this->selectedBranch = $id;
    }

    #[On('branch-dynamic-dropdown')]
    public function setBank($id): void
    {
        $this->bank_id = $id;
    }
};

?>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="{{ Auth::user()->userType != 2 ? 'col-sm-10' : 'col-sm-12' }}">

        <select class="select2 form-control form-control-md form-control-solid" placeholder="Branch" id="branch"
            name="branch" data-parsley-required-message="Please Select Branch." data-parsley-required="true"
            autocomplete="off" wire:model="selectedBranch">

            <option value=" ">Select Branch</option>

            @isset($branch)
                @foreach ($branch as $row)
                    <option value="{{ $row->id }}" @selected($selectedBranch == $row->id)>
                        {{ $row->name }}
                        ({{ $row->code . '-' . $row->region }})
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            @endisset

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="{{ Auth::user()->userType != 2 ? 'col-sm-2' : '' }}">
        @if (Auth::user()->userType != 2)
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text justify-content-center">
                    <a><i class="show-modal bi bi-plus-circle-fill h-100 showBranchModel"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

@script
    <script>
        $(".showBranchModel").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($("#bank_id").val() < 1) {
                notyf.error("Please Select Bank First");
                $('#branch').empty();
                $('#branch').append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '')
                    .text('Select Branch'));
                $('#addBranchModel').modal('hide');
            } else {
                $('#addBranchModel').modal('toggle');
            }
        });
        Livewire.hook('morph.updated', ({
            component,
            el
        }) => {
            $('#branch').select2({
                theme: 'bootstrap-5',
                width: '100%',
            });
        })
        Livewire.hook('morph.added', ({
            el
        }) => {

            $('#branch').select2({
                theme: 'bootstrap-5',
                width: '100%',
            });
            $('#addBranchModel').modal('hide');
        });

        $("#branch").change(function(e) {
            if ($("#bank_id").val() < 1) {
                notyf.error("Please Select Bank First");
                $('#branch').empty();
                $('#branch').append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '')
                    .text('Select Branch'));
            }
        });
    </script>
@endscript


Thanks in advance
